# Python 3.3.0 -- unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, args, packing

This is my function

```
def f(*a,b):
    print (sum(a) , b)
```

Following call causes the error

```
f([x for x in range(100)] , b=0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#61>", line 1, in <module>
    f([x for x in range(100)] , b=0)
  File "<pyshell#59>", line 2, in f
    print (sum(a) , b)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

This is working fine when i do not use sum(a) and use only a instead , pls let me know what's wring with this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unpack the list in order to pass the list into `a`:

```
f(*[x for x in range(100)], b=0)
# ^
```